# Django how to transform queryset into json?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates

My views.py looks like this:

```
def index(request):
mydata = mymodel.objects\
              .values('district')\
              .annotate(total=Count('district'))\
              .order_by('total')
aggregate = json.dumps(list(mydata), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
context = {'aggregate': aggregate}

return render(request, 'polls/index.html',context)
```

and in my index.html, my code is this:

```
var aggregate = '{{ aggregate }}'
```

However, when I did `console.log(aggregate)` in the browser, it gives me this string:

```
[{&quot;district&quot;: &quot;ISLINGTON&quot;, &quot;total&quot;: 663}, {&quot;district&quot;: &quot;HACKNEY&quot;, &quot;total&quot;: 669}, {&quot;district&quot;: &quot;HARINGEY&quot;, &quot;total&quot;: 1230}, {&quot;district&quot;: &quot;WALTHAM FOREST&quot;, &quot;total&quot;: 1947}]
```

I expect this should be in the JSON format. I am still learning Django, could anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey you can use {{ aggregate|safe }} :)

Comment: Thank you! This perfectly works!